# How to provide default value as "true" to a boolean field jackson property

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am using jackson api **@JsonProperty** annotation for creating a model and i need to give default value as **true** to a boolean property(by default it is false). The **defaultValue** attribute of **@JsonProperty** only takes string. Can anybody suggest how can i provide default value as true to a boolean model property

I have tried the following way, but it doesnt work

```
@JsonProperty(value = "field1", required = false)
@ApiObjectField(name = "field1", description = "field1")
private boolean field1 = true;
//getters and setters
```

Answer (score 4):

Below code should work

```
@JsonProperty(value = "required")
private boolean required = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor annotated with the `@JsonCreator` that receives all json properties you want to set to your object, and set a default value to whatever input field that has a null value.

```java
@JsonCreator
MyObject(@JsonProperty("field1") Boolean field1) {
   this.field1 = field1 == null ? true : field1;

}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested the code above.

Comment: I have few properties with @JsonIgnore annotation as well, should i include them in the constructor as well ?

Comment: You don't need to do that afaik

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Serialize, then add it :

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)
private boolean field1;
```

Write the extension similar to:

```
public class MyCustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> {

    public MyCustomSerializer() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        //...
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in field getter too.

like:

```
public Boolean getField1() {
        this.field1 = field1 == null ? true : field1;
        return field1;
}
```